# Setting a new start date for the time series

Tags: python

I have a time series that starts at, let's say 1 July, 2022 and goes on till 30 Sept 2022. I want to set a new start date and end date for the same time series, let's say 5 July, 2023 which goes on till 5 Oct, 2023. I have multiple such time series, for which I have a set of new start and end dates. How do I reindex all these time series and keep the same values?

I tried

```
x.reindex(pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.date_range(start=y\[0\], end=y\[1\], freq="D")), method='ffill')
```

but that doesn't work because it gives only the last value of my time series spread across the whole new period. I want the time series replicated as it is on the new set of dates.

Comment: If the only shifting the index (no change in frequency, no change in length) you could simply add a `pd.Timedelta` to the old index and reindex.